# Spring Context upgrade from 4.3.2 to 5.3.13 - Issue with bean override

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-context, spring-starter

We have upgraded spring context in our application from 4.3.2 to 5.3.13. In the latest spring context bean overriding is restricted by default. So we have enabled the bean overriding by setting the spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true.  By doing so we ran into an issue where the app was **unable to create a bean for database connectivity**.

If in case we do not use the spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true, we are running into bean creation issue as follows.

The bean 'connectionFactory', defined in class path resource [com/company/myorg/my/bank/dept/configuration/MQConnectionFactoryConfiguration.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [com/company/myorg/by/bank/sale/configuration/MQConfiguration.class] and overriding is disabled.

We have tried renaming the bean too, that did not work. Can someone share ideas on how to resolve this please ?

======= MQConfiguration====

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application-${IafConfigSuffix:default}.properties")
public class MQConfiguration {
    @Setter
    private static Logger logger;

    @Value("${host-name}") @Setter
    private String hostName;

    @Value("${port}") @Setter
    private int port;

    @Value("${channel}") @Setter
    private String channel;

    @Value("${time-to-live}") @Setter
    private int timeToLive;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("connectionFactory") @Setter
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    public MQConfiguration() {
        logger = getLogger();
    }

    @Bean(name = "jmsTemplate")
    public JmsTemplate provideJmsTemplate() {
```

==== MQConnectionFactoryConfiguration =======

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application-${IafConfigSuffix:default}.properties")
public class MQConnectionFactoryConfiguration {
    @Setter
    private static Logger logger;

    @Value("${host-name}") @Setter
    private String hostName;
    @Value("${port}")  @Setter
    private int port;
    @Value("${channel}")  @Setter
    private String channel;

    public MQConnectionFactoryConfiguration() {
        logger = getLogger();
    }

   ** @Bean(name = "connectionFactory")**
    public ConnectionFactory buildConnectionFactory() throws JMSException {
```

=========DataSourceConfiguration=====

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfiguration {
    @Bean(name="db2DataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.db2")
    @Primary
    public DataSource db2DataSource() {
        return getDataSourceBuilder().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "jdbcDb2")
    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("db2DataSource") DataSource datasource {
        return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(db2DataSource);
    }

    protected DataSourceBuilder getDataSourceBuilder() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create();
    }
```

We upgraded spring-boot-starter-parent(From 1.4.0 to 2.4.13) , spring-context (from 4.3.2 to 5.3.13), spring-boot-starter (From 1.4.0 to 2.4.13), spring-boot-starter-web and spring-boot-starter-test (From 1.4.0 to 2.4.13), spring-boot-starter-tomcat (From 1.4.0 to 2.4.13), org.codehaus.janino (from 2.7.8 to 3.0.8)

[**Click here to see changes made to pom file**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNtFD.png)

We tried to set spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true which caused the datasource to DB failing.
We have tried renaming the bean too, that did not work

Expectation is, someone to help us out with a solution or an alternative approach.

Comment: *We have upgraded spring context in our application from 4.3.2 to 5.3.13.* don't. Don't just upgrade random jars in your environment. You are using Spring Boot you should be upgrading your whole Spring Boot stack not just 1 jar. And yes bean-overridding has been disabled in newer versions of Spring Boot for a good reason, fix the overridding properly.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for your response. We did make additional changes to spring eco system we are using apart from spring context. I should have added some additional details about all the changes yesterday. I just edited my question and added some additional details. Please do have a look.

Comment: Don't manage Spring Context if you are using Spring Boot. That is being managed already, but as stated overridding has been disabled by default. YOu should fix your configuration. As you haven't included everything this will be impossible to answer. Remove the `spring-context` dependency and any version you have for the `spring-boot-starter-*` dependencies as those are al managed by the `spring-boot-starter-parent`. YOu don't need `spring-boot-starter` as a dependency and remove the `junit` dependencies, those are already part of `spring-boot-starter-test`.